# Could not load file or assembly(dll file path+name) or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: powershell, dll, import-module

When trying to perform-

```
Import-Module 'C:\\Program Files\\Nimble Storage\\bin\\Nimble.Powershell.dll'
```

through program, I am receiving below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\Nimble
>   Storage\bin\Nimble.Powershell.dll' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The same works when ran directly from Powershell but in the above case, facing issue.

C# program used and have used statement:

```
Collection< PSObject > resultCollection = runspaceInvoke.Invoke("Import-Module 'C:\\Program Files\\Nimble Storage\\bin\\Nimble.Powershell.dll'", null, out errors);
```

Comment: The module is x86 and you are using x64 PowerShell would be my guess or vice versa

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "through program"? What program? How?

Comment: @EBGreen- By program I meant, C# program. In there, have used  statement: 
Collection<PSObject> resultCollection = runspaceInvoke.Invoke("Import-Module 'C:\\Program Files\\Nimble Storage\\bin\\Nimble.Powershell.dll'", null, out errors);

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

EBGreen is right. Need to see your code bro. In absence of that, something like the following should work:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

class foo {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] {"'C:\\Program Files\\Nimble Storage\\bin\\Nimble.Powershell.dll'"} );
        ...
    }
}
```

Check out [Creating an InitialSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203829(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.